# Unity Texture2D Find polygon corners

Tags: polygon, detection, vertices

After hours of searching I want to ask now:

How I can detect the x/y positions of all corners from a png?

http://s13.postimg.org/ed5iqzkl3/vertices.png

Can you tell me how I proceed I must? Or exists a lib or something else?

Comment: I would try OpenCV for that, if any thing would help here. There is C# port of it, but frankly speaking I tried to make it work but I couldn't. But there are some packages in asset store that made it work. And finally just to say: it is extreamly hard to do what you try to do.

Comment: computers can't do this yet.  (You may as well ask "how do I speak to my computer".)  As Jerry says, get OpenCV which is the main research project on this -- sometimes it works a little.  Get this to use OpenCV https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088

Comment: also Mat you should explain ***what you are actually trying to do***, there is probably another way

Comment: Hm okay, thank you for your feedback. I need the corner-detection to set the path of a polygon-collider programmatically.

Comment: This is a part of an asset which I'm developing at the moment. Thats why I cannot use other assets for this and I'm already brooding for days over it.